# Numpy list of matrixes as dataset in TensorFlow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

there!

I have a list of n 30x7 matrixes (so I guess it's a 3D array) and another list of n labels (basically TRUE or FALSE). How can I use this as a dataset for TensorFlow? Most tutorials use images, so I can't find how to do it for my case.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's effectively an image, any of the image based tutorials should help you out. If you want to follow tutorials for images, e.g. convolutional neural networks you'll want to `reshape` your 30x7 matrix to include 1 "color" channel. For example: `tf.reshape(data_matrix, shape=[30, 7, 1])` will just change the dimensionality to `[30, 7, 1]` without affecting the actual shape of the data any.

If you batch these together you'll have a dataset of size `[batch_size, 30, 7, 1]` now.

Now you've got things in the right format for working through some tutorials on convolutional networks.

The bigger question you should ask is whether you want to treat your data as an image and apply a convolution network to it. The most fundamental question to ask of your data is whether the patterns you are expecting the network to extract have some 2D spatial locality. For example, an image is effectively processed by looking for patterns over a small window typically of size [3x3] or [5x5] at each layer of the network. Does it make sense to look at your data in such a way?

If so, great, convolutional networks are your thing. If the data doesn't have any kind of 2D spacial meaning, then you might start by simply flattening the data to a `[batchsize, 210]` size vector and feeding it through a fully connected neural network.

Perhaps, instead each row of the matrix represents some data, and there is a logical ordering to the sequence of rows from 1 to 30 (or alternatively by column from columns 1 to 7). If the data is most logically represented as a sequence of rows (or columns) then you will probably be better off looking into RNNs, recurrent neural networks, which operate on sequences more effectively.

In any case look into `tf.reshape`, and `tf.stack`. And consider doing most of this pre-processing work in numpy, it's always easier to debug in numpy.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now I get how to build my dataset with the images. And what about the labels? Should I do the same? Create an 1D-1 element vector with the boolean value for each image and then batch the n labels together?

I'm doing this because there's an article that used stacked autoencoder and they used the same thing, 30x7 matrixes (in fact 30x14 because they concatenated two matrixes), I have to do it with another method, thinking about an RBM.

Comment: If you're doing classification you usually have labels in the shape [batch_size, num_classes] where the 2nd axis is a one-hot vector. Tensorflow has a `tf.one_hot` function that will convert a 1D list of class IDs to the one-hot representation necessary for the loss function.

Comment: Yeeeeah, got it now! Thank you so much, David!